# Calculator for Memory / Bits/ Bytes Size like numerical calculator

Tags: windows, android, calculator

Can you please recommend any software / tool (for Windows 7 and Android) for memory sizes calculation (Bits / Bytes) like numerical calculator. For eg. input `12.5 GB + 5.8 MB + 1392 KB` then click on *Calculate* button it should show the result.

Comment: Show the result in what capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Google](http://www.google.de) or [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

Although both websites require an Internet connection, it's as simple as it probably can get as far as the input method is concerned:

1. Open Google or WolframAlpha in a web browser.
   WolframAlpha has also got an app.
2. Enter `12.5 GB + 5.8 MB + 1392 KB`.
   Optionally provide the desired output unit: `12.5 GB + 5.8 MB + 1392 KB in MB`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows PowerShell already has that capability. [Numbers can take suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24474017/995714) that represent the units in base 2. Just type `12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB` and you'll have the size in bytes. To convert to other units divide by the corresponding unit

[image: PowerShell calculate size]

If you need to use decimal units then scale the values manually: `12.5e9 + 5.8e6 + 1392e3` (G = 1e9, M = 1e6, K = 1e3)